# Adding a pointer to a struct to a slice

Tags: go

I'm trying to add a pointer to a struct to a slice, but I can't get rid of this error:

```
cannot use NewDog() (type *Dog) as type *Animal in append:
    *Animal is pointer to interface, not interface
```

How can I avoid this error? (while still using pointers)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal interface {
  Speak()
}

type Dog struct {
}

func (d *Dog) Speak() {
  fmt.Println("Ruff!")
}

func NewDog() *Dog {
  return &Dog{}
}

func main() {
  pets := make([]*Animal, 2)
  pets[0] = NewDog()
  (*pets[0]).Speak()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal interface {
  Speak()
}

type Dog struct {
}

func (d *Dog) Speak() {
  fmt.Println("Ruff!")
}

func NewDog() *Dog {
  return &Dog{}
}

func main() {
  pets := make([]Animal, 2)
  pets[0] = NewDog()
  pets[0].Speak()
}
```

You don't need a Slice of pointers to Animal interfaces.

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values

Answer (score 2):

just change your code to:

```
func main() {
  pets := make([]Animal, 2)
  pets[0] = NewDog()
  pets[0].Speak()
}
```

a interface value is already an implicit pointer.

Comment: I wanted to clarify; an interface value is **not** an implicit pointer. The type `*Dog` (pointer to Dog) implements the interface, not the type `Dog` - that's why.